# Python: Import multiple images from a folder and scale/combine them into one image?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, scaling, pixel

I have a script to save between 8 and 12 images to a local folder. These images are always GIFs. I am looking for a python script to combine all the images in that one specific folder into one image. The combined 8-12 images would have to be scaled down, but I do not want to compromise the original quality(resolution) of the images either (ie. when zoomed in on the combined images, they would look as they did initially)

The only way I am able to do this currently is by copying each image to power point.

Is this possible with python (or any other language, but preferably python)?

As an input to the script, I would type in the path where only the images are stores (ie. C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\My Pictures\BearImages)

EDIT: I downloaded ImageMagick and have been using it with the python api and from the command line. This simple command worked great for what I wanted: `montage "*.gif" -tile x4 -geometry +1+1 -background none combine.gif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to outsource the image manipulation part to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). It has a [montage command](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) that gets you 90% of the way there; just pass it some options and the names of the files in the directory.

Comment: I have downloaded ImageMagick and have been looking into this. I am browsing to my folder where all the images are stored: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Pictures and then am starting by just using the command line tool. I believe the commands would be something like this: `$ montage -adjoin -coalesce ..."`. How to do you tell the montage command to look a particular folder. I browsed to the folder in question using the command line, but I have not been able to get it to work. I also tried the python APIs for this program, but also no luck

Comment: I didn't see an argument for montage that would use a directory instead of a list of individual files. The last 10% will be to use Python to get a list of files in the desired directory (`os.listdir(string_containing_path)`), append the filenames to a string containing the montage command, and run it using `subprocess.call`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to zoom into the images, you do *not* want to scale them. You'll have to rely on the image viewer to do the scaling as they're being displayed - that's what PowerPoint is doing for you now.

The input images are GIF so they all contain a palette to describe which colors are in the image. If your images don't all have identical palettes, you'll need to convert them to 24-bit color before you combine them. This means that the output can't be another GIF; good options would be PNG or JPG depending on whether you can tolerate a bit of loss in the image quality.

You can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to read the images, combine them, and write the result. You'll need to create a new image that is the size of the final result, and copy each of the smaller images into different parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).
The [handbook](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) contains several examples on both opening files, combining them and saving the result.

Comment: I was looking through that, but I do not really know where to start. I thought about using the `merge` function, but they must be the same size

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to lay the different images out next to each other on a big canvas. Then figure out how big each picture should be on this canvas and create one that is this big, the resize and position each of the images onto the new canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is turn the images into numpy matrices, and then construct a new, much bigger numpy matrix to house all of them.  Then convert the np matrix back into an image.  Of course it'll be enormous, so you may want to downsample.